# bootstrap typeahead with max height and scrollable

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead, scrollable

I'm trying to make the `twitter bootstrap` typeahead dropdown menu scrollable when I put a `max-height` to its class.

The problem is that the function that the plugin uses for sorting the results with the `key_up` or `key_down` doesn't scroll to the hidden options.

I've tried modifying the `keydown` function like this:

```
next: function (event) {

  //original code
  var active = this.$menu.find('.active').removeClass('active')
    , next = active.next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this.$menu.find('li')[0])
  }
  next.addClass('active');

  //modification
  this.$menu.animate({scrollTop: next.position().top}, 0);
}
```

But apparently the `jquery` `.position()` used to do the animation in the modification I used does not return appropiate values.

Please note that I need to use the typeahead a lot in a big form of more than 150 inputs, so please give me a general solution.